# Cannot read property 'toLocaleString' of undefined. Angular 5 ngx-charts

Tags: angular, angular5, ngx-datatable, ngx-charts

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnNoW.png)[Cannot read property 'toLocaleString' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWWja.png)on my component.ts i am using this method to take the data from json

```
getChartProducts() {

        this.TicketService.getAlladminPage(this.number, this.size, this.sort, this.orderByColumn)
          .subscribe(
            (chart: any[]) => {

              let item = 0;

              if (chart['content']) {
                while(item < chart['content'].length){

                  let chartItem = {
                    'name' : chart['content'][item].name,
                    'price': chart['content'][item].price
                  };

                  this.chart.push(chartItem);
                  item ++;
                }

                console.log( this.chart);
              }
            });

      }`
```

i also set

```
`
     chart: { name :string, price :number}[] = [];
view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  showYAxisLabel = true;`
```

and my HTML

```
` <ngx-charts-bar-vertical
                                [view]="view"
                                [scheme]="colorScheme"
                                [results]="chart"
                                [gradient]="gradient"
                                [xAxis]="showXAxis"
                                [yAxis]="showYAxis"
                                [legend]="showLegend"
                                [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
                                [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
                                [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
                                [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
                                (select)="onSelect($event)">
                              </ngx-charts-bar-vertical>`
```

Any idea for this error? i tried chart: { "name":string, "price" :number}[] = []; but again the same error

I am using Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.0.2
"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "7.4.0",

Comment: Where is `toLocaleString` being invoked?

Comment: @user184994 what do you mean?

Comment: Your error says `Cannot read property 'toLocaleString' of undefined`, which means somewhere the code is trying to call `toLocaleString`. In that error, there is probably whats called a stack-trace, which will show where the error occured. Can you add the whole error to your question?

Comment: @user184994 i uploaded an image with the error

Comment: So it looks like, in your SeriesVerticalComponent, you have a function called `update`. Can you add that code (and any relevant code that it calls into) please?

Comment: @user184994 this component is from the ngx-charts library. From series-vertical-component.js :
SeriesVerticalComponent.prototype.ngOnChanges = function (changes) {
        this.update();
    };

Comment: It's too big to post it here

Comment: Can you `console.log` the value you're passing in for the data (i.e. your `chart` value) please? It looks like you may have an undefined value in there

Comment: @user184994 i add an image on post console log

Comment: It looks like `ngx-charts` is expecting each entry to have a property called `value`, but your data doesn't. It only has a property called `price`

Comment: @user184994 That's it!!! Thank you mate!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a **Grouped** Vertical Bar Chart, you need to use:

```
ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d
```

Rather than:

```
ngx-charts-bar-vertical
```

Comment: I assume that meant ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d

Comment: Diego, yes, your assumption is correct. Thanks for catching this, I've updated the response accordingly.  Note that the naming pattern is the same whether horizontal or vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Your data needs to have a property called `value`, but your data only has a property called `price`.

Just update your data to include a `value` property, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
the above error still occurs for charts such as Grouped Vertical Bar Chart, Grouped Horizontal Bar Chart etc this looks like a bug from ngx-charts
the input for this is 

[
  {
    "name": "Germany",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "2010",
        "value": 7300000
      },
      {
        "name": "2011",
        "value": 8940000
      }
    ]
  },
​
  {
    "name": "USA",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "2010",
        "value": 7870000
      },
      {
        "name": "2011",
        "value": 8270000
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

they expect value in the outer array, but if we send value their, there is no meaning

```
i.e [
{
"name": "Germany",
"value": 234324,
"series": [
]
},
...
]
```